# PHP not inserting autoincrement field in a MySQL temporary table

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a temporary table with the following PHP script

```
$query = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE people(id int(11) not null auto_increment, first_name varchar(25), second_name varchar(25), primary key(id))";
$q=$pdo->prepare($query);
$q->execute();
```

I then tried to insert data to this table with the following script

```
$query2 = "INSERT INTO people(first_name, second_name) VALUES(:firstname,:secondname)";
$q2=$pdo->prepare($query2);
$q2->bindValue(':firstname', $firstname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q2->bindValue(':secondname', $secondname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q2->execute;
```

The data I am trying to insert comes from another table. At first this seemed as a problem caused by an elementary error but I cannot figure out where the problem is because when I run this script (see below), I see that all fields were created

```
$query3 = "DESCRIBE people";
        $q3 = $con->prepare($query3);
        $q3->execute();
        $row = $q3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
print_r($row);
```

Comment: Please do not abuse the snippets tool

Comment: `$q3 = $con->prepare($query10);` What is `$query10`?

Comment: Did you tryied setting your `id` column to `primary key` inline ? `... TABLE people ( id int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, ...);`

Comment: @Phillip, i have edited the error

Comment: @Zeratops i have tried but no success

Comment: Thanks alot @Philipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query2 = "INSERT INTO people(first_name, second_name) VALUES(:firstname,:secondname)";
$q2=$pdo->prepare($query2);
$q2->bindValue(':firstname', $firstname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q2->bindValue(':secondname', $secondname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q2->execute;
```

The `()` for the `execute()` method are missing.

Additionaly:

If you are trying to fill the table from another table, without other steps in between, you could do this directly via mysql:

```
$query2 = "INSERT INTO people(first_name, second_name)
select firstname, secondname from otherTABLE where something = 'xy'";
$pdo->exec($query2);
```

Doing it directly in the database would reduce the chance for errors in php trying to do the same.

The rest of your script is correct, I tested it locally:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

$query = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE people(id int(11) not null auto_increment, first_name varchar(25), second_name varchar(25), primary key(id))";
$q = $pdo->prepare($query);
$q->execute();

$firstname = 'test';
$secondname = 'what';

$query2 = "INSERT INTO people(first_name, second_name) VALUES(:firstname,:secondname)";
$q2 = $pdo->prepare($query2);
$q2->bindValue(':firstname', $firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q2->bindValue(':secondname', $secondname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q2->execute();

$pdo->exec("INSERT INTO people(first_name, second_name) SELECT 'prename', 'surname'");

$result = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM people');
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result->fetchAll());
exit;
```

displays:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(4) "test"
    ["second_name"]=>
    string(4) "what"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(7) "prename"
    ["second_name"]=>
    string(7) "surname"
  }
}
```

Comment: The missing () was a typo. The table is a temporary table

Comment: So does the auto_increment field stay empty when you try to execute your script?